# Is there any way to change default post format in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

For some reason I need to change the default post format instead of standard format. I know we can change this via

> Dashboard -> Settings -> Writing

But is there any code snippet that can be put into function.php to achieve this?

Comment: When I google `change default post format in wordpress`, I see plenty of useful info. Does nothing in those results help you?

Comment: can you advice several info as I really didn't get any useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72030/25765) you can use the `option_default_post_format` filter, e.g.:

```
function so16854774_default_post_format( $format )
{
    global $post_type;
    return ( $post_type == 'post' ? 'aside' : $format );
}
add_filter( 'option_default_post_format', 'so16854774_default_post_format', 10, 1 );
```